Nav-menu issue in mobile view
So the short story is, I have created a website, and I now seem to be running into an issue with the nav-menu, my nav-menu has a sub menu that drops down to expose some other menus,  This works perfectly fine in desktop view, drop-down menus works great but as soon as I go into mobile view the drop-down menu stops working
<nav id="navmenu" class="navmenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html#hero" class="active">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#features">Features</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#"><span>Services</span> <i class="bi bi-chevron-down toggle-dropdown"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Client Login (Coming Soon)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="fullwebsite.html">Full Website Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="singlelandingpage.html">Landing Page Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="multipagedesign.html">Multi Page Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="addon.html">Add-On Features</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <i class="mobile-nav-toggle d-xl-none bi bi-list"></i>
    </nav>


/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Navigation Menu
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
 
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navmenu .dropdown ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: var(--nav-dropdown-background-color);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100%; /* Align dropdown below parent item */
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease, top 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 99;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  
    .navmenu ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      list-style: none;
      align-items: center;
    }
  
    .navmenu li {
      position: relative;
    }
  
    .navmenu a,
    .navmenu a:focus {
      color: var(--nav-color);
      padding: 18px 15px;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-family: var(--nav-font);
      font-weight: 400;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      white-space: nowrap;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  
    .navmenu a i,
    .navmenu a:focus i {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 0;
      margin-left: 5px;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  
    .navmenu li:last-child a {
      padding-right: 0;
    }
  
    .navmenu li:hover>a,
    .navmenu .active,
    .navmenu .active:focus {
      color: var(--nav-hover-color);
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px 0;
      background: var(--nav-dropdown-background-color);
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      left: 14px;
      top: 130%;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 4px;
      z-index: 99;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown ul li {
      min-width: 200px;
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown ul a {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 15px;
      text-transform: none;
      color: var(--nav-dropdown-color);
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown ul a i {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown ul a:hover,
    .navmenu .dropdown ul .active:hover,
    .navmenu .dropdown ul li:hover>a {
      color: var(--nav-dropdown-hover-color);
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown:hover > ul {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      top: 100%; /* Prevent overlapping by ensuring dropdown is fully below */
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown .dropdown ul {
      top: 0;
      left: 100%; /* Align nested dropdowns to the right */
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
    }
    
    .navmenu .dropdown .dropdown:hover > ul {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      top: 0; /* Nested dropdown aligns horizontally */
      left: 100%;
    }
  
    .navmenu .megamenu {
      position: static;
    }
  
    .navmenu .megamenu ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px;
      background: var(--nav-dropdown-background-color);
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      position: absolute;
      top: 130%;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity: 0;
      display: flex;
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 4px;
      z-index: 99;
    }
  
    .navmenu .megamenu ul li {
      flex: 1;
    }
  
    .navmenu .megamenu ul li a,
    .navmenu .megamenu ul li:hover>a {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: var(--nav-dropdown-color);
    }
  
    .navmenu .megamenu ul li a:hover,
    .navmenu .megamenu ul li .active,
    .navmenu .megamenu ul li .active:hover {
      color: var(--nav-dropdown-hover-color);
    }
  
    .navmenu .megamenu:hover>ul {
      opacity: 1;
      top: 100%;
      visibility: visible;
    }
  }
  
  /* Mobile Navigation */
  @media (max-width: 1199px) {
    .mobile-nav-toggle {
      color: var(--nav-color);
      font-size: 28px;
      line-height: 0;
      margin-right: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: color 0.3s;
    }
  
    .navmenu {
      padding: 0;
      z-index: 9997;
    }
  
    .navmenu ul {
      display: none;
      list-style: none;
      position: absolute;
      inset: 60px 20px 20px 20px;
      padding: 10px 0;
      margin: 0;
      border-radius: 6px;
      background-color: var(--nav-mobile-background-color);
      overflow-y: auto;
      transition: 0.3s;
      z-index: 9998;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }
  
    .navmenu a,
    .navmenu a:focus {
      color: var(--nav-dropdown-color);
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-family: var(--nav-font);
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight: 500;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-between;
      white-space: nowrap;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  
    .navmenu a i,
    .navmenu a:focus i {
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 0;
      margin-left: 5px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transition: 0.3s;
      background-color: color-mix(in srgb, var(--accent-color), transparent 90%);
    }
  
    .navmenu a i:hover,
    .navmenu a:focus i:hover {
      background-color: var(--accent-color);
      color: var(--contrast-color);
    }
  
    .navmenu a:hover,
    .navmenu .active,
    .navmenu .active:focus {
      color: var(--nav-dropdown-hover-color);
    }
  
    .navmenu .active i,
    .navmenu .active:focus i {
      background-color: var(--accent-color);
      color: var(--contrast-color);
      transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px 0;
      background: var(--nav-dropdown-background-color);
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      visibility: hidden;
      top: 130%;
      left: 0;  /* Set left to 0 for better alignment */
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 4px;
      z-index: 99;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    }

    
  
    .navmenu .dropdown ul ul {
      background-color: rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
    }
  
    .navmenu .dropdown>.dropdown-active {
      display: block;
      background-color: rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.03);
    }
  
    .mobile-nav-active {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  
    .mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav-toggle {
      color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 32px;
      top: 15px;
      right: 15px;
      margin-right: 0;
      z-index: 9999;
    }
  
    .mobile-nav-active .navmenu {
      position: fixed;
      overflow: hidden;
      inset: 0;
      background: rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.8);
      transition: 0.3s;
    }
  
    .mobile-nav-active .navmenu>ul {
      display: block;
    }
  }


(function() {
  "use strict";

  /**
   * Apply .scrolled class to the body as the page is scrolled down
   */
  function toggleScrolled() {
    const selectBody = document.querySelector('body');
    const selectHeader = document.querySelector('#header');
    if (!selectHeader.classList.contains('scroll-up-sticky') && !selectHeader.classList.contains('sticky-top') && !selectHeader.classList.contains('fixed-top')) return;
    window.scrollY > 100 ? selectBody.classList.add('scrolled') : selectBody.classList.remove('scrolled');
  }

  document.addEventListener('scroll', toggleScrolled);
  window.addEventListener('load', toggleScrolled);

  /**
   * Mobile nav toggle
   */
  const mobileNavToggleBtn = document.querySelector('.mobile-nav-toggle');

  function mobileNavToogle() {
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle('mobile-nav-active');
    mobileNavToggleBtn.classList.toggle('bi-list');
    mobileNavToggleBtn.classList.toggle('bi-x');
  }
  mobileNavToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', mobileNavToogle);

  /**
   * Hide mobile nav on same-page/hash links
   */
  document.querySelectorAll('#navmenu a').forEach(navmenu => {
    navmenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (document.querySelector('.mobile-nav-active')) {
        mobileNavToogle();
      }
    });

  });

  /**
   * Toggle mobile nav dropdowns
   */
  document.querySelectorAll('.navmenu .toggle-dropdown').forEach(navmenu => {
    navmenu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
      this.parentNode.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('dropdown-active');
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
  });

  /**
   * Preloader
   */
  const preloader = document.querySelector('#preloader');
  if (preloader) {
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      preloader.remove();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Scroll top button
   */
  let scrollTop = document.querySelector('.scroll-top');

  function toggleScrollTop() {
    if (scrollTop) {
      window.scrollY > 100 ? scrollTop.classList.add('active') : scrollTop.classList.remove('active');
    }
  }
  scrollTop.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
  });

  window.addEventListener('load', toggleScrollTop);
  document.addEventListener('scroll', toggleScrollTop);

  /**
   * Animation on scroll function and init
   */
  function aosInit() {
    AOS.init({
      duration: 600,
      easing: 'ease-in-out',
      once: true,
      mirror: false
    });
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', aosInit);

  /**
   * Initiate glightbox
   */
  const glightbox = GLightbox({
    selector: '.glightbox'
  });

  /**
   * Frequently Asked Questions Toggle
   */
  document.querySelectorAll('.faq-item h3, .faq-item .faq-toggle').forEach((faqItem) => {
    faqItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
      faqItem.parentNode.classList.toggle('faq-active');
    });
  });

  /**
   * Init swiper sliders
   */
  function initSwiper() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".init-swiper").forEach(function(swiperElement) {
      let config = JSON.parse(
        swiperElement.querySelector(".swiper-config").innerHTML.trim()
      );

      if (swiperElement.classList.contains("swiper-tab")) {
        initSwiperWithCustomPagination(swiperElement, config);
      } else {
        new Swiper(swiperElement, config);
      }
    });
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", initSwiper);

  /**
   * Correct scrolling position upon page load for URLs containing hash links.
   */
  window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      if (document.querySelector(window.location.hash)) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          let section = document.querySelector(window.location.hash);
          let scrollMarginTop = getComputedStyle(section).scrollMarginTop;
          window.scrollTo({
            top: section.offsetTop - parseInt(scrollMarginTop),
            behavior: 'smooth'
          });
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  });

  /**
   * Navmenu Scrollspy
   */
  let navmenulinks = document.querySelectorAll('.navmenu a');

  function openModal(title, description) {
    document.getElementById('modalTitle').innerText = title;
    document.getElementById('modalDescription').innerText = description;
    document.getElementById('designModal').style.display = 'block';
  }
  
  function closeModal() {
    document.getElementById('designModal').style.display = 'none';
  }
  
  // Close the modal when clicking outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == document.getElementById('designModal')) {
      closeModal();
    }
  }
  
  function navmenuScrollspy() {
    navmenulinks.forEach(navmenulink => {
      if (!navmenulink.hash) return;
      let section = document.querySelector(navmenulink.hash);
      if (!section) return;
      let position = window.scrollY + 200;
      if (position >= section.offsetTop && position <= (section.offsetTop + section.offsetHeight)) {
        document.querySelectorAll('.navmenu a.active').forEach(link => link.classList.remove('active'));
        navmenulink.classList.add('active');
      } else {
        navmenulink.classList.remove('active');
      }
    })
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', navmenuScrollspy);
  document.addEventListener('scroll', navmenuScrollspy);

})();


[So in my css code i have this section. In that section i have two lines, Visibility and opacity,
Original:
Visibility: hidden
Opacity: 0
New Code:
Visibility: visible
Opacity: 1
Changing only those two lines actually make the box appear but looks weird](https://i.sstatic.net/nCMKW8PN.png)

I cant readily reproduce the issue; it seems that some missing HTML causes JavaScript errors. It might help to provide a working example to demonstrate.
